# Escaping mod_rewrite keywords

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, regex

I am currently using the following rule in mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule /request/([0-9]+)$ /request.php?id=$1
```

That rule does not work, while "requests" instead of "request" in the regexp works.
My assumption is that "request" is a keyword of mod_rewrite or apache, but I cannot verify that.

When I use "request", the redirect works but $1 is always empty , although the url is definetely correct.

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect, and what shows up instead? More details pls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `request` is not a [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html) keyword. Keywords always have bounds: `[QSA]`, `${mapname:key|default}`, `%{NAME_OF_VARIABLE}`...

Comment: Ok, but why does it work with "requests", but not with "request" then? Is any character in the latter interpreted as a special regexp character? The strange thing is that the redirect works, but $1 is always empty for "request".

Comment: You still need to define "work" and "does not work" but I suspect you just have another rule somewhere else that's conflicting with this one.

Comment: "Work" means that for "requests", apache passes the request to the appropriate php file and the id passed to the file ($1) is the value after "requests/". For "request", the request is also passed to request.php, but $1 is empty and $_GET is empty. But I will try to remove all other rules and test this one isolatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by disabling "Multiviews" in the apache configuration.